# how do i store the struts2 tag checkboxlist elements in the database?

Tags: struts2

If i wanted to store the struts2 tag checkboxlist elements in the database ,How do i save it in the database .I mean how do i work with the checkboxlist tag ,

like how do i declare it in the table .How do i use it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here are [several](http://maspanji.wordpress.com/2008/05/15/using-checkboxlist-in-struts2/) [different](http://www.easywayserver.com/blog/struts2-checkbox-tag-example-check-box-example/) [examples](http://www.roseindia.net/struts/struts2/struts2uitags/checkboxlist-tag.shtml) showing how to use the checkboxlist in your Action class and view.

Once the checkbox is submitted to your action, you'll have a List populated with the checked `String` values.  You can then save those Strings in your database in an appropriate field type (i.e. for MySQL that could be [CHAR or VARCHAR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html)).